# Laravel вопрос по таблице с миграцией

Tags: laravel, миграция

Как в Laravel при добавлении миграции добавить чтоб $table->bigIncrements('id'); начинался не с 1 а с 100 к примеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В миграции в методе `up` добавить `\DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;");`

```php
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        // ...
    });
    \DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 200000;");
}
```

P.S. Это касается только `mysql`. На других DB не проверял.